# Where do I insert the batteries in my Polaroid camera?

Tags: polaroid

I have a polaroid camera from around the year 2000...where do the batteries go? I've looked and looked! I tried looking behind the film too. Is there anybody who knows?

Comment: What is the exact model you have? Post a photo if you don't know.

Comment: @osullic I can't figure out how to get the pic on here

Answer (score 4):

If you're talking about a Polaroid camera that takes packs of self-developing film, the battery is part of the pack itself.

If yours isn't working, the solution is to move the film itself into a working pack.  For details, see: https://danfinnen.com/article/what-to-do-if-you-have-a-dead-battery-in-a-polaroid-film-cartridge/